# Difference between data set, random element and sample

Tags: probability, terminology

In  Jun Shao's Mathematical Statistics, page 91-92:

*In statistical inference and decision theory, the data set is viewed as a realization or observation of a random element defined on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathcal{P})$ related to a random experiment. The probability space $\mathcal{P}$ is called the population. The data set or the random element that produces the data is called a sample from $\mathcal{P}$*

My confusion comes from the following two sentences: 1) *the data set is viewed as a realization or observation of a random element*, and 2) *The data set or the random element that produces the data is called a sample*.
In the first one, it says that the data set is viewed as a realization of a random element. In the second one, it says that the data set or the random element that produces the data is called a sample. Then, in the first one take the data set as a realization of a random element, and in the second one, both are the same. I am a bit confused about that.

Anyone can shed a bit of light on it? Thank you.

Comment: We have *many* good posts on this topic: [search our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=sample+outcome+random+variable+score%3A10+is%3Aanswer).

Comment: Thank you. I have taken a look, but I do not find the example of the tickets in the box with what is exactly a sample, a population, a data set, etc... given the definition I wrote in my question.

Comment: Maybe that's because in your comment you are trying to ask multiple questions but we require each thread to focus on a single question.  That only means you need to consult several threads for answers to your questions.

Comment: Well, I think that understanding the different concepts of the same definition is a single question. Asking separately I (and people) will not see the entire picture. It's a confusion that I have from the same definition.